# Incluir link em um container

Tags: html, css, html5

Tenho um container no meu código e preciso que ele seja clicável, com `href`, vamos supor que ao clicar ele direcione para "Google.com". Como posso fazer isso?

```
<div class="project-2 v-center">
<div><!--v-center-->
    <div class="container">
            <h1>COMPADRE IPSUM</h1>
        <p>Eiiitaaa Mainhaaa!! Esse Lorem ipsum é só na brincadeira!!.</p>
    </div>
    <!--/.container-->
</div>
<!--/v-center-->
```

A classe:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Pode definir melhor o que é clicável? Se for a questão do cursor em forma de "mãozinha", é só acrescentar **cursor: pointer;** na classe .container

Comment: Desculpe, preciso que ele leve pra um link com href e tals. Só que tentei colocar como coloco em botões e etc mas não foi. não sei se tem algo a ver com a class ou se é questão de escrita mesmo.

Comment: A questão então seria "transformar" o div em um link? Via javascript pode ser feito: `<div class="container" onclick="window.location.href='http://google.com.br'">`

Answer (score 3):

A troca do `DIV` por um `A` permite o uso do `href` tradicional, e funciona mesmo sem JS:

CSS:

```css
.container {
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    text-decoration:none;
    ... outras estilizações necessárias ...
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="project-2 v-center">
<div><!--v-center-->
    <a class="container" href="http://google.com">
        <h1>COMPADRE IPSUM</h1>
        <p>Eiiitaaa Mainhaaa!! Esse Lorem ipsum é só na brincadeira!!.</p>
    </a>
    <!--/.container-->
</div>
<!--/v-center-->
```

Esta solução só passa na validação em HTML5.

Em HTML4, não eram válidos elementos de bloco dentro de `<A>`. Na prática funcionavam, mas não passavam na validação, portanto, um risco de efeitos colaterais a ser evitado.

<sub>Leitura complementar: **[Block level links and accessibility](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201109/block_level_links_and_accessibility/)**<sup>(en)</sup></sub>

<sub>Esta resposta é equivalente à segunda sugestão da resposta do @Guilherme Bernal, que considero melhor que a primeira, e por isso elaborei com os detalhes relevantes.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Para tal o caminho mais simples é usar javascript no evento onclick da `div`:

```
<div style="cursor: hand;" onclick="location.href='www.google.com'">
  Qualquer coisa aqui
</div>
```

O problema disso é que não vai se comportar exatamente igual a um link ordinário. Você não pode por exemplo clicar com o direito para copiar a url, ou clicar com o botão do meio. Uma forma um pouco melhor é em vez de tentar fazer a div se comportar como um link, é fazer o link se comportar como uma div. Para isso use o `display: block`:

```
<a href="www.google.com" style="display: block;">
  Qualquer coisa aqui
</a>
```

Comment: O meu problema é que não entendo de JS ainda, então basicamente tenho que me virar nessa com HTML 5, até porque estou usando um código que já foi feito, e preciso só colocar o link, porque esse container já tem background e varias coisas. só queria colocar ele como link mesmo, existe alguma maneira de fazer isso sem ter que mudar o style.css, mexendo apenas no index?

Comment: @Vinícius Qualquer uma das opções que mostrei pode ser feita modificando apenas o seu html, se assim prefere. O código está na respota...

Comment: A segunda sugestão é melhor.

Comment: Altamente desaconselhável usar eventos JavaScript, como o `onclick`, inline no HTML.

Comment: @Rael Sem dúvida. O HTML idealmente não deve conter nem comportamento nem visual. Apenas a estrutura hierarquica e semântica de elementos.

Answer (score 2):

Eu recomendo você colocar a tag  dentro das tags de marcação de título e parágrafo, ficando o código dessa forma:

```
<div class="project-2 v-center">
    <div><!--v-center-->
        <div class="container">
            <h1><a href="http://www.google.com">COMPADRE IPSUM</a></h1>
            <p><a href="http://www.google.com">Eiiitaaa Mainhaaa!! Esse Lorem ipsum é só na brincadeira!!.</a></p>
        </div>
        <!--/.container-->
    </div>
    <!--/v-center-->
</div>
```

Dessa forma você passa na validação da W3C sem problemas.

Caso queira manter a estrutura do container precisa usar um pouco de Javascript (jQuery) no caso:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.container').click(function(){
            window.location="http://seu.site.com/";
        });
    });
</script>
```

Não esquece de importar a biblioteca jQuery.

E no css basta adicionar o atributo `cursor:poiter`

Espero ter ajudado.
Boa Sorte!